# htaccess serve images from Amazon AWS

Tags: .htaccess, amazon-web-services

I can't get this to work.

I need to use htaccess to serve images on AWS as if they were on my website.

Example:  http://www.example1.com/images/meme.jpg
should show the image from
https://bucket1.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/meme.jpg
But it's NOT a redirect.  The address is still shown as http://www.example1.com/images/meme.jpg in the browser

A colleague is using this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ http://bucket1.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/$1 [P]
```

HOWEVER when I do that I get this:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchBucket</Code>
<Message>The specified bucket does not exist</Message>
<BucketName>www.example1.com</BucketName>
<RequestId>4CE66A21A22EC3CA</RequestId>
<HostId>
BlAEYrdEO+xm4fGSwjyeZX/pn7IVfHPNGiLJpWRta/PNxekFnLuXHnbX2EGjkIdY2gVM65E2ymI=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Why does it seem to be putting my domain as the bucket name???  Ripping my hair out for this one.